# Cameron-Martin like RKHS

Tags: stochastic-calculus, kernels

Hello,

I know that $k(x,y)=min(x,y)$ is the reproducing kernel of the Cameron Martin space of all i.i.d. RVs of Brownian motion at different times, with the $cov$ inner product.

What is the RKHS generated by $k(x,y)=min(f(x),f(y))$ for some $f$?

Comment: i guess that change of variable of Ito integral should be involved